# debugging code using opencv fails with segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, gdb

Trying to debug some c++11 code that utilizes the opencv library, yields a segmentation fault in gdb.

I am debugging following function using gdb in linux.

```
MatchedFeatures extract_best_features(vector<Mat> imgs)
{
  MatchedFeatures result;

  cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
  //cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
  //cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = ORB::create();

  for (auto it = 0; it < imgs.size(); ++it) {
    vector<KeyPoint> keyPoints;
    Mat descriptors;
    f2d->detect(imgs[it], keyPoints);
    f2d->compute(imgs[it], keyPoints, descriptors);
    result.imgFeatures.push_back(ImgFeatures{imgs[it], keyPoints, descriptors});
  }

  BFMatcher matcher;
  vector< DMatch > matches;
  matcher.match(result.imgFeatures[0].descriptors,
                result.imgFeatures[1].descriptors,
                matches);

  cout << matches.size() << "\n";

  //extract top 10
  sort(matches.begin(), matches.end(),
            [&](const DMatch x, const DMatch y) -> bool
            { return x.distance <= y.distance; });
  result.matches = vector<DMatch>(matches.begin(),matches.begin()+5); // <- debug fails here and matches is empty in debug mode
  return result;
}
```

The segmentation fault is yielded when the debugger reaches the point where I slice the `matches` vector. Inspecting the `matches` variable and looking at the stacktrace revealed that `matches` is empty.. However, only empty in debug mode.

The code works perfectly fine when I just run it normally, **it only fails when debugging**.

I noticed that the BFMatcher spawns a lot of threads when performing the match, so I suspect that the problem arises because of threads. Though I just started learning c++, so I can only guess whats wrong.

Is there some way to "wait" for the threads to finish properly in gdb?
Or is there some other trick that allows me to debug and inspect this kind of code in c++ without getting segmentation faults and empty results from side-effect-generating-procedures such as `match` in `BFMatcher`?

***EDIT (solved the problem):***

*So apparently full paths should be used when using filepaths as arguments when running a program in cgdb (and not relative paths to the executable or paths using the home folder shortcut ~/)... I am now able to debug my program perfectly fine..*

Comment: How do you ensure there are 5 items in `matches`?  A better test would be:
`size_t lastItem = std::min(matches.size(), 5);`, and then `vector<DMatch>(matches.begin(), matches.begin() + lastItem)`

Comment: Same thing here:  `matcher.match(result.imgFeatures[0].descriptors,                result.imgFeatures[1].descriptors,`  You are assuming you have at least 2 items in `imageFeatures`.  What if there is only 1 item or is empty?  You are accessing elements out of bounds.  Add the first comment, plus the answer I gave, and you have a lot of visible issues with the code that does not have issues with threads.

Comment: `matches.begin(),matches.begin()+5` can you verify that matches.size is 6 or bigger before computing that line? Maybe in Debug Mode you dont successfully read the image because of wrong pathes or sth., maybe resulting in empty or different matching vector.

Comment: ah ok, you already have seen that matches is empty. So analyze why if differs in debug mode. May candidate is still that you did read a different image or no image at all because of wrong relative pathes. Try to display intermediate results etc...

Answer (score 1):

Code that crashes when run in a debugger but not otherwise could be an indication of you using uninitialized data and missing null-pointer checks. When running in a debugger, the debugger generally clears all memory used by the program, including local variables. That means pointers will be null-pointers, and dereferencing a null-pointer generally leads to a crash.

When not running in a debugger, local variables are not initialized, so there is no null-pointer access. On the other hand since local data is (when not running in a debugger) uninitialized the values are *indeterminate* and using uninitialized data leads to *undefined behavior*. It might *seem* to work though.

---

If on the other hand you had crashes (or unexpected results) when *not* running in a debugger, but it works fine inside the debugger, it's still basically the same problems with using uninitialized local data, but you *do* have null-pointer checks.

The best way to debug these kind of problems is to use a memory debugger, for example [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 1):

One issue may have nothing to do with threads.  There is an issue whether threads are or are not used.

The issue is this:

```
  //extract top 10
  sort(matches.begin(), matches.end(),
            [&](const DMatch x, const DMatch y) -> bool
            { return x.distance <= y.distance; });   // <-- Suspect
```

Your sort criteria does not seem to follow a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).  Anytime you see a `<=` as the "less than" criteria, it is almost always a mistake.  A strict-weak order is required for `std::sort` to operate correctly.

Change the line to this:

```
 { return x.distance < y.distance; });
```

Whether this solves your problem completely, I can't say.  But it *is* a problem you have to address to proceed testing.

---

Since you are using `gcc`, I just would like to mention that the Visual Studio's debug runtime would detect a problem like this.

The way it detects it is by calling your sort criteria twice.  The first time with the arguments in one order, the second time with the arguments swapped.  The runtime compares both results, and if they do not follow a strict-weak ordering, the runtime asserts.  For your case, if `x.distance == y.distance`, then the debug runtime would have asserted immediately.

Comment: I tried to remove the sorting from the code, but with same result when debugging (segmentation fault). However, thanks a lot for the tip on using VS, and on the weak ordering. I might play a little around with VS in the weekend, if I manage to install and configure opencv for windows.

Comment: See my comment in your original post.  Don't use magic numbers assuming that you know the size.  Always program defensively by using things like `std::min` to throttle the number to a size that cannot fail.